# C++ - Zip Utils unzipping from memory to memory

Tags: c++, zip

While searching how to easy (without any dlls,...) unzip in C++, I came around [Zip Utils](http://www.wischik.com/lu/programmer/zip_utils.html).

I download data from server (compressed in PHP using `gzencode()`) to local buffer, now I'd like to uncompress it either using Zip Utils or something else.

Lets say I have :

```
char zipped[100000];

char unzipped[100000];
```

now I'd like to unzip data from one buffer to other, how exactly do I do that using Zip Utils?

EDIT:
I've tried unzipping myself, but I cannot get it working. Here is the one example of how I tried.

```
 HZIP hz = OpenZip(zipped, sizeof zipped, "");
            char buf[1024]; ZRESULT zr = ZR_MORE; unsigned long totsize = 0;
            while (zr == ZR_MORE)
            {
                ZIPENTRY ze; GetZipItem(hz, 0, &ze);
                zr = UnzipItem(hz, 0, unzipped, sizeof unzipped);
                unsigned long bufsize = 1024; if (zr == ZR_OK) bufsize = ze.unc_size - totsize;
                    totsize += bufsize;
            }
            CloseZip(hz);
```

Comment: The link you provided has some good examples.

Comment: Thing is I tried using those examples, but unfortenaulty it didn't worked for me. Thats why I'm asking a question here.

Comment: In order to get help you'll need to show exactly what you've done so far and exactly what code is giving you an issue.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code there, it does not belong in a comment.

Comment: _'A bit hard to post source in a comment'_ Yes, that's why you've been asked to edit your question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've succeeded to solve my problem using source provided on [this page](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/algorithms/compression/article.php/c5125/Two-Classes-for-Doing-Gzip-in-Memory.htm)

Probably the easiest code yet I saw, and it works flawlessly!